# Only get pages where a field matches one of a set of values

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a storelocator in wordpress where I use zipcodes to filter for distance. I then create I string with all zipcodes that are within range and make a string with all those zipcodes separated by comma's. This works fine and returns something like this:

```
5062,5063,5061,4163,5060,5059,5056,5076,5066,5070,5071,5074,5268,5034,5035,5037,5027,5033,5032,5031,5030,5029,5028,5038,5039,5036,5049,5048,5047,5046,5045,5044,5043,5042,5041,5040,5026,5025,5010,5009,5008,5007,5006,5005,5004,5003,5002,5001,5000,5011,5012,5013,5024,5023,5022,5021,5020,5019,5018,5017,5016,5015,5014,5296
```

Now I want to get posts where the zipcode **CONTAINS** one of these values. I figured something like this would work:

```
$query_adresses = array (
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'cat'       => $_GET["cat"],
    'post_type'=> 'adressen',
    'posts_per_page'   => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'postcode',
            'value'   => array($final_target_zips),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        )
    )
  );
```

Sadly it doesn't work and just returns all posts that match the other arguments. Keep in mind that zipcodes in the posts consist of the numbers but also have two letters attached to them like: `5021GH`. Only the numbers need to be checked though. I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Your `meta_query` is wrong, it should be an array of an array, not just an array

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed my arguments but now it returns nothing while it should return plenty of posts

Comment: Try `$final_target_zips` instead of `array($final_target_zips)`

Comment: Ah right! But shouldn't it be explode(",", $final_target_zips) then?

Comment: I tried both and I get nothing. Is IN the right operator if you want to see if a string contains another string?

Comment: The value parameter can be either a sting or an array. Just to note, I only saw your edit now, so value should be a string, and then change compare to LIKE. I'm not quite sure if it will work, but give it a try

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to work though

Comment: I will see if I can play with this this afternoon. You can also try `REGEXP` or `RLIKE` as possible compare values.